# How to write a StructureMap Scanner for this case

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have these registrations in a registry and am trying to figure out the correct way to implement them with a scanner instead of manual registration.

```
For<ISomeView>.Use(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler)
For<IOtherView>.Use(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler)
For<IAnotherView>.Use(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler)
```

And so on. I have ever one of my interfaces inherent from `IView` to be used as a marker interface.

My original attempt came out looking like this

```
public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
{
    Type _pluginType = typeof(IView);

    if (type.CanBeCastTo(_pluginType) && type.IsInterface)
    {
        string name = type.Name;
        registry.AddType(_pluginType, type, name);

        registry.For(_pluginType).Use(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler);
    }    
}
```

This however caused my physical ASP.NET pages to be registered as itself instead. This is what I got from WhatDoIHave()

```
the_page_aspx (ASP.the_page_aspx) - 36d0cdb2-7118-4a1d-94a0-8de1b5ddc357 - 
Configured Instance of ASP.the_page_aspx, App_Web_4q8pukge, Version...
```

**Edit:** To respond to KevM's comment what I want to acheive is anytime StructureMap needs to inject any single of my IView's that it resolves it by by returning `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`

So if I'd call `ObjectFactory.Resolve<ISomeView>()` I would get `(ISomeView)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`

If I have a constructor that was `SomePresenter(IListView listView, IEditView editView)` that those would be resolved to `(IListView)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` and `(IEditView)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler`.

I could do this with numerous `For<>.Use()` statements as in my example which means I should be able to achieve it with a scanner instead of needing to explicitly register each one manually. My interfaces will always be named I_____View if the naming convention would help for writing the scanner. I'm just not sure what I need to use in the if statement I have above for the `Process()` method.

**Update:** With the answer from @KevM it pointed me in the right direction to this

```
public class ViewScanner : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.IsA<IView>() && !type.IsConcrete())
        {
            registry.For(type).Use(c => HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

(IsA<> is just an extension for IsAssignableFrom since to me the usage of it feels backwards)

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for the scanner to do for you. You wish it to add all your view classes by name? How are you pulling things out of the container? One thing that sticks out is that you are registering IView to use HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler multiple times. Did you mean to register the type being processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is close to what you are looking for.

```
public interface IView { }
public class View : IView { }
public class View2 : IView { }

public static class IckyStaticMonster
{
    public static IView Current { get; set;}
}

[TestFixture]
public class configuring_concrete_types
{
    [Test]
    public void TEST()
    {
        var container = new Container(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.Convention<ViewScanner>();
            });
        });

        var current = new View2();
        IckyStaticMonster.Current = current;

        var view2 = container.GetInstance<View2>();

        view2.ShouldBeTheSameAs(current);
    }
}

public class ViewScanner : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        Type _pluginType = typeof (IView);

        if (_pluginType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && _pluginType.IsInterface)
        {
            registry.For(type).Use(c=>IckyStaticMonster.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do I'll have to test it out and I'll let you know!

Comment: This was almost it but your answer gave me the info I needed.

Comment: Glad to help. I have to give some credit to Josh Flanagan he helped too.